# date command with formatter string is not executed in cron under Linux

Tags: linux, cron, date

I have the following crontab:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* *   * * *   /bin/date                >> /tmp/date.log  2>&1
* *   * * *   /bin/date "+%F_%H-%M-%S" >> /tmp/date2.log 2>&1
```

The first one executes correctly .. writing the current date to `/tmp/date.log`
The second one doesn't work. `/tmp/date2.log` is never created. The only difference is that the second date command has a formatting string as parameter. Outside of the cronjob the second date command (`/bin/date "+%F_%H-%M-%S"`) works fine.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

My system:

uname -a

```
Linux corsair 4.15.0-50-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:46:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lsb_release -a

```
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa
Release:    19.1
Codename:   tessa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unescaped percent signs in the command are replaced by newlines, see [crontab(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab). You need to put a backslash in front of them.